# Solving linear recurrence after finding values via Quadratic Equation

Tags: recurrence-relations

My HW asks me to solve the following Linear Recurrence:

> $f(0) = 3 $
>
> $f(1) = 1$
>
> $f(n) = 4f(n − 1) + 21f(n − 2)$

Unfortunately my professor ran through the concept of Linear Recurrence rather quickly so I'm stuck. But this is what I've done so far:

1). Assuming $x^n = f(n)$, I rewrote the equation as $x^n = 4x^{n-1} + 21x^{n-2}$.

2). I then divided each part of the equation using the common factor $x^{n-2}$ to get $x^2 = 4x + 21$, a quadratic.

3). I then used the quadratic formula to get two values, $6$ and $2$.

From here I don't know how to proceed. I know I'm trying to write a closed form of the above equation, right? How do the values I've found figure into that? I'm also not sure what the salience of 'the boundary conditions' are (are those $f(0) = 3$ and $f(1) = 1$?).

Comment: How did using the quadratic formula on $x^2-4x-21$ lead to $6$ and $2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first steps were correct. First, assume $x^{n}$ with $x\neq0$
is a solution. Plugging this into the recurrence, we get
$$
x^{n}=4x^{n-1}+21x^{n-2}.
$$
Dividing through by $x^{n-2}$ gives the quadratic
$$
x^{2}=4x+21.
$$
This has roots $x=-3$ and $x=7$. Since the recurrence is linear,
any linear combination of solutions is also a solution. Therefore, we assume that our solution is of the form
$$
f_{n}=c_{1}(-3)^{n}+c_{2}7^{n}.
$$
All that's left to do is to make sure that $f_{n}$ satisfies the
initial conditions:
\begin{align*}
3 & =c_{1}(-3)^{0}+c_{2}7^{0}=c_{1}+c_{2};\\
1 & =c_{1}(-3)^{1}+c_{2}7^{1}=-3c_{1}+7c_{2}.
\end{align*}
Solving this linear system gives $c_{1}=2$ and $c_{2}=1$ so that
the final recurrence is
$$
f_{n}=2(-3)^{n}+7^{n}.
$$
You can also [check your answer using Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%5Bn%5D%3D4*f%5Bn-1%5D%2B21*f%5Bn-2%5D,%20f%5B0%5D%3D3,%20f%5B1%5D%3D1).

Comment: This was hugely helpful, thank you for this. One brief question: my professor mentioned that in some cases, the base cases provided may not be valid for the final recurrence that may emerge in some linear recurrences. Maybe I heard him wrong, but when he said this I found it very confusing. Are you familiar with this idea? And how does the boundary conditions play into this?

Comment: I am not sure what he meant by this, sorry.